# Include Menu PHP

Tags: php, html, css, menu, include

Estou com dificuldades de incluir um código php com html em outra pagina usando o include, no caso o código é um menu escrito em html porem com extensão php.   Quando tendo incluir o código do arquivo menu.php no arquivo index.php acusa um erro no arquivo menu.php linha 2 de "<". Vou postar os códigos para facilitar a compreensão do problema. Esse menu.php é so para fins de estudo.

**Arquivo includes/menu.php:**

```html
<?php <head>
<title>Construção de interface em HTML e CSS</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<style type="text/css">
  @import "estilo/layout.css";
</style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <header>
      <h1>The Door</h1>
    </header>
    <div id="login">
      <ol>
        <li><a href="">Login</a>
        </li>


      </ol>
    </div>

    <nav>

      <ol>
        <li><a href="">Principal</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Faculdade</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Links</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Outros</a>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </nav>
    <section id="destaque">
      <figure>
        <img src="imagens/gatostop.jpg">
        <figcaption>Gatinhos zueiros</figcaption>
      </figure>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Lorem ipsum dolor
        sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
        consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
      </p>
    </section>
    <main>
      <section>
        <article>
          <h3>Título 1</h3>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
            in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing
            elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
          </p>
        </article>
        <article>
          <h3>Título 2</h3>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
            in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing
            elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
          </p>
        </article>
      </section>
      <aside>
        <div>Link externo</div>
        <div>Conteúdo adicional</div>
        <div>Publicidade</div>
      </aside>
    </main>
    <footer>Development by
      <h4>Rafael<h4></footer>
  </div>
 </body>
?>
```

**Arquivo index.php:**

```html
<?php

include "includes/menu.php";

?>
```

Comment: no seu `menu.php` tem as tag `<?php` e `?>` e nenhum código `PHP`, você poderia retirar as tags e ver se funciona.

Comment: essa é a questão amigo, se eu remover a tag php, como vou incluir o meu menu em outras paginas?

Comment: Ele vai chamar o arquivo `.php`. Ou você tem que fazer como a resposta do @Allan Ramos.

Comment: @Rafael2F, normalmente se usa trechos de código em PHP (em um arquivo `.php`, óbvio) numa estrutura HTML, e não o contrário. Ou seja, você vai abrir a tag `<?php` somente onde precisar usar PHP (imprimir uma variável na tela, por exemplo).

Comment: @Rafael2F você quer chamar o menu em outra view? Está usando algum framework?

Comment: não estou usando framework

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Retire as tags `<?php ?>` do arquivo menu.php (Você vai deixar só html, e salvar com a extensão php como já estar).

e depois ça a chamara normalmente:

```
<?php
include "includes/menu.php";
?>
```

O problema está ocorrendo porque você está tentando imprimir errado no php.

Onde se tem:

```
<?php <head>
<title>Construção de interface em HTML e CSS</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
...
```

Deveria ser assim:

```
<?php echo "<head>".
"<title>Construção de interface em HTML e CSS</title>".
"<meta charset="UTF-8">";
```

E como você só tem html nessa página php poderia simplesmente tirara o `<?php ?>` ficando assim:

```
<head>
<title>Construção de interface em HTML e CSS</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
...
```

Comment: Milrak eu fiz como voce disse e funcionou, porem eu ainda não entendi se isso é uma boa pratica, como o menu.php é um arquivo php sem tags? eu adicionei as tags <html></html>, fiz certo ou poderia deixar sem?

Comment: @rafael2f me desculpa não saber se isso é uma boa prática de programação, deixa a galera mais experiente responder. Mas se o problema é em ter uma página .php só com html, só mudar a extensão para o html e fazer o include na página html -> `include "includes/menu.html";` (Acho que assim você não estará pecando.

Comment: Ei Milrak, mas o include não é exclusivo do php? eu fiz como voce disse e funcionou ate eu edicionar uma tag <section> no arquivo index, depois de adicionada retornou um erro. Oque pode ter acontecido?

Comment: @Rafael2F Acabei de testar aqui e funcionou com html, sendo assim não é exclusiva. Mostra o erro aí da tag `<section>`

Answer (score 4):

O problema é que ele está interpretando as tags HTML como parte da sintax do PHP, já que você colocou tudo dentro do `<?php ?>`. Para mostrar um conteúdo HTML no PHP você tem 2 alternativas, sendo elas:

- Coloque o `echo` logo depois da tag de abertura do PHP, para que ele identifique as tags do HTML.
- Tire as tags de abertura/fechamento do PHP - caso você não use nada relacionado a linguagem nesse código.

#### Exemplo com echo

```
echo '
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Meu Site</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="meuId">
                <p>Meu parágrafo</p>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
';
```

#### Exemplo sem tags de abertura

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Meu Site</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="meuId">
            <p>Meu parágrafo</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

### Modularizando HTML

Acabei de ler um comentário seu, e parece que você está querendo modularizar o HTML, o que é uma boa prática, já que o mesmo trecho de código será usado diversas vezes. Vou postar um código abaixo dando uma lida básica no seu código de como você poderia fazer essa divisão.

#### index.php

```
<?php
    include 'template/header.php';
    incldue 'template/menu.php';
?>

<section>
    código da section
</section>
<main>
    código dentro do main
</main>

<?php
    include 'template/footer.php'
?>
```

Aqui eu fiz a inclusão de 3 arquivos PHP, sendo eles:

- header.php - Este arquivo conterá desde a abertura do seu `<html>` até a abertura da tag `<body>`.
- menu.php - Este conterá a sua tag `<nav>` com o menu.
- footer.php - Este conterá a parte de `<footer>` e fechamento das tags `</body>` e `</html>`.

Considerei o conteúdo da `<section>` e `<main>` como aquele que seria diferente dentro daquela página.

#### header.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Construção de interface em HTML e CSS</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <style type="text/css">
            @import "estilo/layout.css";
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
```

#### menu.php

```
<div id="container">
    <header>
        <h1>The Door</h1>
    </header>
    <div id="login">
        <ol>
            <li><a href="">Login</a></li>
        </ol>
    </div>
    <nav>
        <ol>
            <li><a href="">Principal</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Faculdade</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Links</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Outros</a></li>
       </ol>
    </nav>
</div>
```

#### footer.php

```
    <footer>Development by <h4>Rafael<h4></footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: cara, eu tenho que fazer isso para todas as tags? incluindo o header? eu estou muito perdido, acho que sua resposta foi muito sucinta.

Comment: @Rafael2F Comentário atualizado.

Comment: Exatamente isso Alan, fiz dessa forma ai tambem, obrigado por esclarecer o fato de ser ou não boas práticas.